# Standard (non-admin) user on macOS can remove applications installed by admin

Tags: security, user-account, launchpad

I experienced this issue on macOS Monterey 12.1 & 12.2. I don't know if older macOS versions have the same behavior.

The issue is that the app installed from App Store under admin account can be removed by non-admin (standard) user in Launchpad by pressing 'x' icon on that app. Admin password is not asked. The app is removed globally for all users from /Applications folder.

For me it seems like a security issue. So I first emailed to Apple. But their response was that they "do not see any security implications" in it.

How is that not a security issue?

Answer (score 2):

Uninstalling an app is specifically permitted by the system, you are not compromising the security of the system because it's specifically being allowed.